# Creating a list with sequential elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist, stream, java-stream

Is there an utility method in Java ( perhaps stream() )to generate list of sequential elements, such as time that increased by constant value (seconds, minutes, hours)?

```
bySeconds(Start_time="10:00:00" interval=2, count=100)=>{"10:00:00", "10:00:02", "10:00:04", "10:00:06", "10:00:08", ......}

byMinutes(Start_time="10:00:00", interval=5, count=100)=>{"10:05:00", "10:10:00", "10:15:00", "10:20:00", "10:25:00", ......}

byHours(Start_time="10:00:00", interval=1, count=100)=>{"10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", ......}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `Stream.iterate` is designed for this purpose. For example:

```
Stream.iterate(LocalTime.of(10, 5), Duration.ofMinutes(5)::addTo)
```

Will generate an infinite stream of times starting at 10:05 and increasing by 5 minutes. If you wanted a specific end point you could use `Stream.limit` to get a certain number or either add a predicate to the `Stream.iterate` or use `Stream.takeWhile` to end at a certain point. To covert to a list, use `Stream.toList`.

If you want the times converted to a specific string format then use a `DateTimeFormatter`. For example to convert to the format in the example in your question:

```
.map(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME::format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `IntStream` with `IntStream.range(start, endExclusive)`, then use `.map()` or `.mapToObj()` on the stream to map the values to something else. All values are sequential, so `IntStream.range(0, 10)` will yield a stream containing `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.